# Angular material dialog with table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to put a material table inside of dialog so that the table header won't be scrollable, but the table content will be scrollable, something like this:
[image]

I know, that dialog supports "mat-dialog-content", but I don't know how to add it to `tbody`.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="ordersTableSource" [hidden]="isLoading || !ordersTableSource.data.length">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ 'carat-orders-dialog.table.id' | translate }}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let order">
            <span>...</span>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="location">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ 'carat-orders-dialog.table.location' | translate }}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let order">
            <span>...</span>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="customer">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ 'carat-orders-dialog.table.customer' | translate }}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let order">
            <span>...</span>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr class="row" mat-row *matRowDef="let order; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Angular Material solution would be to edit your **Header** row to have a *sticky* parameter:

`<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>`

As reference, please see this example from the Material website: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-sticky-header

If you have multiple header rows, you can specify the *sticky* parameter for each Header row.

Comment: Super! I got it working. I did like this:
<mat-dialog-content>
   <table>
      ....
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
   </table>
</mat-dialog-content>

Answer (score 0):

You can input your table component inside some div container and set to container style. But u must to know, parent element of this container must to has "position: relative"

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I can help if you will create stackblitz demo and i'll post here how to resolve your problem